# reading into table: comma values and quotes SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

i have a string like this

```
something = "something, something1, "something2, something else", something3"
```

i need it to be read into a table like this:

```
field1 = "something"
field2=  "something1"
field3 = "something2, something else"
field4 = "something3"
```

please notice that the double quotes in the `something` string signified that the string inside the quotes is to be placed in one field

anyone know how to do this with an `insert into` statement or some other way? the answer can be purely sql or can be vba with sql.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use single quotes within $something to cause Access to treat the entirety of the quoted section as an atomic unit:

```
something = "something, something1, 'something2, something else', something3"
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the character sequence , " with something the pipe sign for example and then use that as field separator.